# SerialPort reading process doesn't work properly in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I'm developing an application which communicates with my electronic circuit via Port 4. I can send data from the PC to the circuit without a problem; I then get data back from the circuit. However, when I try to get data from my circuit for the second time, I receive incorrect data from it. Any pointers on how to solve this?

This is C# code:

```
byte[] Sent_Byte = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
byte[] Received_Byte = new byte[10];

private void button_sendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I send this data because the circuit is ready to get data
    serialPort1.Write("G");
    serialPort1.Write(Sent_Byte, 0, 6);
}

private void button_getData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I send this data because the circuit is ready to send data
    serialPort1.Write("A");
}


private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        serialPort1.Read(Received_Byte, 0, 10); 
}
```

This is Arduino code:

```
char Control_OP=0;
char Received_Data[6]; 
byte Sent_Data[10];

void loop()
{
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    Control_OP = Serial.read(); // determines whether receiving data or sending data

    if(Control_OP=='G') // receiving data
    {   
      Number=Serial.readBytes(Received_Data,6); 
    }

    else if(Control_OP=='A') // sending data
    {
      Serial.write(Sent_Data,10);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work from a terminal program like hyperterm?

Comment: It's not like that. It has four buttons. Connect, Disconnect, SendData and GetData

Comment: How's it "not like that"? Your circuit doesn't care that there's 4 buttons does it? If it's communicating over the serial port you should be able to talk to it with something like hyperterm. Just open up a connection (with the appropriate settings) and try sending `A` and see if it responds. This is basic serial communication trouble-shooting.

Comment: Number==Serial.readBytes(Received_Data,6); 
is wrong because ==
anywhay, what data do you expect, and what do you receive?

Comment: @MattBurland 

I connect it and I send data from the PC to the circuit by clicking the sendData button without any problem. If I try to get data from the circuit after I send data to the circuit, I fail. I get incorrect data. However, If I execute the programme and connect the circuit and try to get data, It works properly. Getting data works properly at once

Comment: @lesto

Yes there is a mistake but I made that mistake while copying the code here

Comment: Can you post where you initialize Sent_data? Also what are you reciving? The arduino code is missing, maybe you are running out of ram? Or playing with pointer?

Comment: I found the problem but I don't know how to solve it

Here is the array I need to get from the circuit (correct data)

Array[0]=88     
Array[1]=2      
Array[2]=188       
Array[3]=2       
Array[4]=32      
Array[5]=3       
Array[6]=132        
Array[7]=3    
Array[8]=232       
Array[9]=3        
      

Here is the incorrect data      
   
Array[0]=2             
Array[1]=188           
Array[2]=2             
Array[3]=32           
Array[4]=3           
Array[5]=132          
Array[6]=3             
Array[7]=232           
Array[8]=3            
Array[9]=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I changed this code

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
            serialPort1.Read(Received_Byte, 0, 10); 
}
```

into this one

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i <Received_Byte.Length; i++)
            {
                Received_Byte[i] = Convert.ToByte(serialPort1.ReadByte());
            }
    }
```

Thanks everyone for helping me